# Issue with iOS 7 Matchismo assignment 1 Stanford

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I've written code for the first assignment in the iTunesU course on iOS 7 programming from Stanford University. The problem is, when I compile I get a warning that says Method definition for addCard: not found.

This is the code I have in the Deck class. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#import "Deck.h"

@interface Deck()
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *cards;// of Card
@end

@implementation Deck

-(NSMutableArray *)cards
{
if(!_cards) _cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
return _cards;
}

-(void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop
{
if(atTop){
    [self.cards insertObject:card atIndex:0];
}else{
    [self.cards addObject:card];
}
}


-(void)addcard:(Card *)card
{
[self addCard:card atTop:NO];
}

-(Card *)drawRandomCard
{
Card *randomCard = nil;

if ([self.cards count]) {
    unsigned index = arc4random() % [self.cards count];
    randomCard = self.cards[index];
    [self.cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
return randomCard;
}

@end
```

Comment: Point out which line is giving you the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `.h` file, you've named the method `addCard:`, but in your `.m` file, you've spelled the method `addcard:`.

Objective-C is case-sensitive.

Change this line in your `.m` file:

```
-(void)addcard:(Card *)card
```

To look like this:

```
-(void)addCard:(Card *)card
```

Comment: Wow... cant believe I didn't catch that one. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisHooked When someone posts an answer that solves your problem you should accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. This rewards the answers as well as yourself plus it indicates that the question is complete.